# How to get month from month and year value by php

Tags: php-7.1

I get this value

```
$select_month_year = 12/2017
```

Trying this:

```
date('m', strtotime($select_month_year))
```

But output is:

```
01
```

But output should be :

```
12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$select_month_year = "12/2017";
$month = explode('/', $select_month_year)[0];

echo $month;
```

Or

```
$date = date_create_from_format('m/Y', '12/2017');
echo $date->format('m');
```

Comment: I didn't want to apply explode option, use date format.
Seconded option is ok. Thanks @sam.